# Electron User Installer build

Tags: electron, electron-builder

Recently I was installing [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/download) again and noticed it has a new `User Installer` for download. I'm assuming this is an installer that user doesn't have to have the Administrator permission to install. Is that the case? How can I build my application like that? Couldn't find anything on the electron-builder documentation or other building packages...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at electron builder's [NSIS configuration](https://www.electron.build/configuration/nsis):

> The top-level nsis key contains set of options instructing
> electron-builder on how it should build NSIS target (default target
> for Windows).
>
> - oneClick = true Boolean - Whether to create one-click installer or    assisted.
> - perMachine = false Boolean - Whether to show install mode installer    page (choice per-machine or per-user) for assisted
>   installer. Or    whether installation always per all users
>   (per-machine).
>
>   If oneClick is true (default): Whether to install per all users    (per-machine).
>
>   If oneClick is false and perMachine is true: no install mode    installer page, always install per-machine.
>
>   If oneClick is false and perMachine is false (default): install mode    installer page.

In your case, **User Installer** is **per-user** and **System Installer** is **per-machine**. Try to set both `oneClick` and `perMachine` to false when build installer, you will see an installer page like this:

[image]

Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks Hai, will check this asap

Comment: @JoãoMenighin in case of needing more information about per user and per machine, check out of this one: [Installation Context](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/msi/installation-context)